# UIImageView's layer border visible inset

Tags: ios, uiimageview, calayer

Just did this:

```
self.imageView.backgroundColor = color1;
self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
self.imageView.layer.borderColor = color1;
self.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0;
```

Here is screenshot of the problem:

[image: Screenshot of a problem]

I can see image, borders, and image fragments out of the border…

[image]
[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: How did you add your mask? Seems like there is a problem with the mask image

Comment: @CihanT. there are no masking. Just `UIImageView` with colored border in front of filled `UIView`.

Comment: Have you tried doing this with border & cornerRadius directly on the `UIImageView`? ie. `imv.layer.cornerRadius = width/2`, `masksToBounds = YES`, & set borderWidth, borderColor?

Comment: @JackWu a am doing it directly :)

Comment: Right..In that case a workaround of putting into a `UIView` and setting the radius and border on that view will probably work. I think I've done that before...

Comment: @JackWu heh, that is a workaround… My `UIVmageView` has complex bounce animation. It can become laggy on old devices...

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue using the border properties on the layer and managed to solve it by adding a CAShapeLayer on top.
I can't tell you how it will behave on older devices as haven't tested it with many animations and so on, but I really doubt it will slow them down.

Here is some code in Swift:

```
    imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.1137, green: 0.2745, blue: 0.4627, alpha: 1.0)
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.bounds.height / 2.0

    let stroke:CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let rect = imageView.bounds
    let strokePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: imageView.bounds.height / 2.0)

    stroke.path = strokePath.CGPath
    stroke.fillColor = nil
    stroke.lineWidth = 3.0
    stroke.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 0.1137, green: 0.2745, blue: 0.4627, alpha: 1.0).CGColor

    stroke.frame = imageView.bounds
    imageView.layer.insertSublayer(stroke, atIndex: 1)
```

Hope it will work in your case as well

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
self.imageView.layer.shouldRasterize = TRUE;
```

Comment: This changes nothing :(