# UIImageView layer border issue

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UIImageView` and set it's layer's `borderColor`, `borderWidth`, and `cornerRadius` like

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.bounds.height/2.0
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 6
imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

. After this, I expect that border not fully covering `UIImageView`.
My `UIImageView` has 110x110 Size and `cornerRadius` of 55.

### [image]

As you can see, some parts of the image are visible outside border. 
My `UIImageView` is in .pdf format, and it's `maskToBounds = true` 
So, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think u need to draw rounded corner yourself instead of setting the border width, see this link might helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28434313/uiimageviews-layer-border-visible-inset

Comment: Kindly try `imageView.clipsToBounds = true`

Comment: That's likely due to anti-aliasing effects. Make the radius of the image 2 pixels smaller than the radius of the view with the border.

Answer (score 1):

I am using below code and its working perfectly fine. Kindly try

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width/2;
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 6;
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using the same. Think I need update my question.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your pdf file to UIImage using the below code.

```
func drawPDFfromURL(url: URL) -> UIImage? {
    guard let document = CGPDFDocument(url as CFURL) else { return nil }
    guard let page = document.page(at: 1) else { return nil }
let pageRect = page.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)
let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: pageRect.size)
let img = renderer.image { ctx in
    UIColor.white.set()
    ctx.fill(pageRect)

    ctx.cgContext.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: pageRect.size.height);
    ctx.cgContext.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0);

    ctx.cgContext.drawPDFPage(page);
}
 return img
}
```

Then put into your imageview

```
imageView.image = image;
```

Then add your border and all

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 55;
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
imageView.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor];
imageView.borderWidth = 4;
```

Answer (score -4):

Set your UIImageView layer `masksToBounds` property :

```
yourImageView.masksToBounds = YES;
```